# Figure correctly compiled but TikzEdt gives an error

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, editors

I'm using TikzEdt (version 0.2.3.0). I find it convenient since it produces .tikz files directly includable in the main document by an `\input` command.

Everything works fine but, when I compile the code below, TikzEdt gives this error:

> Couldn't parse code. MismatchedTokenException: Expected token ')'.
>   Instead found "," in line 23 at position 39.

even if the compilation is done.

Should I ignore it or be worried about it ("today's warning is tomorrow's error")?

```
% Code prepended -------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
%------------------------------------------------------------------

% My code ---------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\Lossdistribution}{%
    (bassissimos) .. 
    controls (bassos) and (altos) 
    .. (punta) .. 
    controls (altod) and (bassod)
    .. (bassissimod)
}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
no markers, 
ticks=none,
xmin=-4, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=4,
samples=300,
clip=false, 
every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
xlabel={Loss},
ylabel={Probability density}
]

\node[below=0.5] (nulla) at (axis cs: 0, 0)  {$0$}; 
\node[below=0.5] (VaR) at (axis cs: 3.5, 0)  {VaR$_\alpha$}; 
\node[] (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs: 5.4, 1)  {$1-\alpha$}; 
\node[below] (inmezzoallarea) at (axis cs: 4, 0.14)  {}; 

\coordinate (bassissimos) at (axis cs: -4, 0.04) {};
\coordinate (bassos) at (axis cs: -2, 0.1) {};
\coordinate (altos) at (axis cs: -2.5, 2.7) {};
\coordinate (punta) at (axis cs: -1.5, 3.5) {};
\coordinate (altod) at (axis cs: 0, 4.5) {};
\coordinate (bassod) at (axis cs: 1, 0.1) {};
\coordinate (bassissimod) at (axis cs: 6.7, 0.07) {};

\begin{scope}
\clip (axis cs: 3.5, 0) rectangle (axis cs: 6.7, 3);
\fill [gray!30] \Lossdistribution -- (axis cs: 6.7, 0);
\end{scope} 

\draw [name path=curva, thick, smooth] \Lossdistribution;

\draw [-{Stealth[scale=0.7]}] (unomenoalfa) -- (inmezzoallarea);

\path [name path=riga] (axis cs: 3.5, 0) -- (axis cs: 3.5, 4);
\path [name intersections={of=curva and riga}];
\draw[] (intersection-1) -- ({intersection-1} |- {axis cs: 0, 0}); 

\end{axis};

\end{tikzpicture}
%------------------------------------------------------------------

% Code appended ---------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no problem when I compile the main document with "My code" included.

EDIT: I have modified the code inserting `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` (as suggested) but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer please? I noticed that you also did not  accept answers on your other posts; it would be nice if you can accept answers of those who have been helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept your answer since it doesn't solve the problem, please see my reply in chat, thank you!

Comment: Ignoring what is said in the *Status* panel, what does the log under *PdfLaTeX output* say? I get the same message as you, but the actual compilation error is that the `axis` environment is undefined, because `pgfplots` is not loaded. This happens even if `\usepackage{pgfplots}` is added to Settings --> Options --> Compiler.

Comment: Do you intend this?LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 67.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!

Comment: It seems to me the only error present in the .log file (if I have understood what log is to check...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I post this just to *answer the answered*.</sub>

Unfortunately, TikzEdt seems to be definitely no more maintained. One year ago I also wrote to the e-mail address indicated on [its site](http://www.tikzedt.org/links.html), but I got no answer.

I solved the specific problem by uninstalling and re-installing it again but, of course, this is only a workaround.

For any other error which can't be solved this way, the only solution is to change editor (and it's really a pity).

Answer (score 3):

This `Code Prepended` worked for me. I am using `TikzEdt 0.2.3.0`, `Miktex 4.4`, and `Windows 11`.

```latex
% Code Prepended
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%begin{document}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

Seems naive but commenting `%begin{document}` before `\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}` did the trick. After playing around with the temp files, `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\TikzEdt\TikzEdt\0.2.3.0\temp_header.tex` and `C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/TE_temp_previewXXXX.tex`, I noticed that `TikzEdt` has problems managing the character `%`.

**Edit**:
For your example, the problem seems to be related with the use of `axis cs:`, I run it using the following code:

```latex
% --- Code prepended
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

%begin{document}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

% --- main
\newcommand{\Lossdistribution}{%
    (bassissimos) .. 
    controls (bassos) and (altos) 
    .. (punta) .. 
    controls (altod) and (bassod)
    .. (bassissimod)
}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    no markers, 
    ticks=none,
    xmin=-4, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=4,
    samples=300,
    clip=false, 
    every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
    xlabel={Loss},
    ylabel={Probability density}
    ]

    \node[below=0.5] (nulla) at (0, 0)  {$0$}; 
    \node[below=0.5] (VaR) at (3.5, 0)  {VaR$_\alpha$}; 
    \node[] (unomenoalfa) at (5.4, 1)  {$1-\alpha$}; 
    \node[below] (inmezzoallarea) at (4, 0.14)  {}; 
    % 
    \coordinate (bassissimos) at (-4, 0.04) {};
    \coordinate (bassos) at (-2, 0.1) {};
    \coordinate (altos) at (-2.5, 2.7) {};
    \coordinate (punta) at (-1.5, 3.5) {};
    \coordinate (altod) at (0, 4.5) {};
    \coordinate (bassod) at (1, 0.1) {};
    \coordinate (bassissimod) at (6.7, 0.07) {};
    % 
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (3.5, 0) rectangle (6.7, 3);
        \fill [gray!30] \Lossdistribution -- (6.7, 0);
    \end{scope} 
    % 
    \draw [name path=curva, thick, smooth] \Lossdistribution;
    % 
    \draw [-{Stealth[scale=0.7]}] (unomenoalfa) -- (inmezzoallarea);
    % 
    \path [name path=riga] (3.5, 0) -- (3.5, 4);
    \path [name intersections={of=curva and riga}];
    \draw[] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-1)|-(0, 0);

\end{axis};

\end{tikzpicture}

% --- Code appended
\end{document}
```

[image: TikzEdt]

**Tip**: Every time I modify the `code prepended` in TikzEdt's settings, I delete the `temp_header.tex` and `temp_header.fmt` files hidden in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\TikzEdt\TikzEdt\0.2.3.0` to avoid any `Compilation failed with exit code 1` error.

Comment: Thank you for replying after so many years, but even doing what you said I still have the error `Couldn't parse code. MismatchedTokenException: Expected token ')'. Instead found "," in line 23 at position 39.` However, I don't use TikzEdit anymore, since it is no more maintained. Now I use Overleaf to draw my pictures with the auto-compile option. Anyway, +1 for your effort.

Comment: Thank you for the Overleaf tip and the +1! The community needs a new TikzEdt.

Comment: The error `Couldn't parse code. MismatchedTokenException: Expected token '}'. Instead found "-1" which is of type INT in line 47 at position 46.` is still a TikzEdt error. There are no errors in my code if you compile it in another editor (uncommenting `\begin{document}`, of course). Yes, the community needs a new TikzEdt. Unfortunately, I haven't the required skills to code it. Maybe I can dedicate myself to it when I am retired; it could be my hobby :D

Comment: I solved the `INT` error changing the last command `\draw[] (intersection-1) -- ({intersection-1}|-{0, 0});`  to `\draw[] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-1)|-(0, 0);`, just make sure to switch off the `Overlay` to see a clean result. Maybe somewhere near in the future we will have a new TikzEdt. Actually, the authors were working on the v1.0 but never finished.

Comment: TikzEdt hasn't been maintained for years. I think authors stopped working on it.

Answer (score 1):

this post have some years now but I found myself troubling over pgfplots implementation in TikzEdt. I believe I found the solution. Instead of adding *\usepackage{pgfplots}* into one of your styles, add it under *Settings(tab)/Settings/Compiler/Code prepended*.

Works for me!
Piotr

Comment: Thank you but that's what I did, see `% Code prepended` in my MWE. It doesn't work for me, but now I don't use TikzEdit anymore, because it is no more maintained. I prepare my `tikzpicture`s in Overleaf, to have the auto-compile option. However, +1 for having answered after 4 years :)

Comment: Probably not important anymore for you, but maybe the we use(d) different versions of TikzEdt? Mine is 0.2.3.0.

Comment: Same version, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` to your preamble should solve the problem. This is probably caused by different versions of TikZ having minor differences in their features. And this line tells TikZ to compile the TikZ code using a specific version.

Also, this is often good practice to include this line even without a warning to avoid unexpected output because people might have different versions of TikZ installed on their computer.

Comment: Adding \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} doesn't solve the problem. When I compile in TikzEdt the error "MismatchedTokenException" still remains. It solves another warning "running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} into your preamble." when I compile with TeXstudio.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I played around with TikzEdt, it seems like this editor does not fully support the features and syntax of Tikz as reported by some other users. If your TeX compiles it right, there is not problem, it is the problem of the TokzEdt.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it has nothing to do with the problem and could be misleading for the peculiar problem, please consider removing it.